# How do I use the Telerik RadEditor control?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radeditor

Can anyone advise me on how to use the Telerik RadEditor control?  This is the control where a user can enter plain text and save it to database.

What is the process to use the Telerik RadEditor?

Comment: You need to read documentation and expend actual effort.

Comment: In the OP's defense, the telerik site seems 99.99% dedicated to marketing shlock.  I've been trying for the last 15 minutes to find any actual developer-oriented documentation of their tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at [this demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/saveindatabase/defaultcs.aspx) of the Telerik's RadEditor to see a demonstration on how to save to database.